# Is it possible to prevent ORDS from escaping my GeoJSON?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-ords

I have a problem with Oracle ORDS escaping my GeoJSON with "

```
{
"id": 1,
"city": "New York",
"state_abrv": "NY",
"location": "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-73.943849, 40.6698]}"
}
```

In Oracle DB it is stated correctly:

```
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-73.943849, 40.6698]}
```

Need help to figure out why the " are added and how to prevent this from happening

Answer (score 3):

add this column alias to your restful service handler query for the JSON column

```
SELECT id,
       jsons "{}jsons" --this one
  FROM table_with_json
```

Then when ords sees the data for the column, it won't format it as JSON because it already IS json

You can use whatever you want, in your case it should probably be 
"{}location"

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million Jeff!! Works like charm now :D Truly inspiring to see you being active over all these places attempting to help people out! An example for me as a product owner/manager.

Comment: No problem @Sietze - we have so many customers/users here, and talking to and working with customers is a huge component of being a good product manager. Welcome to SO!

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Is this feature in the documentation? I can't seem to find any mention of it.

Comment: @OlafurTryggvason not yet - and that needs fixed